# solve polynomial equation in limited variables

Tags: polynomial-math

A simple question.
The problem is to solve an integer polynomial equation like this:  x+y+z=num, and the int value of x, y, z is supposed to be like this: X1<=x<=X2, Y1<=y<=Y2, Z1<=z<=Z2 , then find out how many x,y,z combinations are there to satisfy that equation.
May be there are more efficient algorithms rather than this:

```
for(int i=X1;i<=X2;i++)
    for(int j=Y1;j<=Y2;j++)
        for(int k=Z1;k<=Z1;k++)
            if(i+j+z==num)
                print i,j,k;
```

I'm not asking for codes but for ideas.
Thanks to anyone who offers helpful information!

Comment: to reduce the number of iterations (second and third iteration) you can use: 
`for (int j=Math.max(Y1, num - i); ...`
(this would work if all numbers are positive)

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm runs in O((X2-X1)(Y2-Y1)(Z2-Z1)) time.

To make it faster, you could have it check if the sum is larger than num, and if it is, then you could pop out of the loop you're in and increment the next larger one. For example, the Y loop could read

```
for(int j = Y1; j <= Y2; j++){
    if(i + j > num){
          j = Y2;
          continue;
    }
    for ( int k = Z1;...){...}
}
```

This would prevent the algorithm from testing some combinations larger than num, thus improving the run time. Note that you can do this for all three loops, including only the variables that have been defined so far (this example doesn't test k because k isn't defined until the third loop).